# Perl - Regex, conditionals and match multiple objects against inconsistent strings

Tags: regex, perl

From a text file I load each line into a variable (`$line`). Each line has a general form, but is not consistent, e.g.

```
[Foo] - Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt £34.99
[BARBAR] ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis £255.25
[BAZZ] - deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. - £500
```

For each line I want a string which

- Does not have the square brackets
- Does not contain leading spaces or non alpha numeric characters e.g. ' - '

To further complicate things I'd like to return the price as a different variable.

A couple of examples of the above data:

```
$var1 = 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt';
$var2 = '£99.99';

$var1 = 'ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis';
$var2 = '£255.25';

$var1 = 'deserunt mollit anim id est laborum';
$var2 = '£500';
```

I have literally no idea where to begin with what is (to me) a really complicated regex.

**Edit**, edge cases...

Turns out that way into the text file there's some edge cases my description didn't cover, for example:

```
[BARBAR] ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis £255.25 (5% off)
[BAZZ] - deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. - £500 (%10 less)
```

Ideally I'd like to store the value (e.g. '10% less','5% off') in a variable called `$discount`, if they exist.

Comment: Rule 1 of dealing with complex regexes: Don't, use separate ones.

Comment: @Sobrique I understand, thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I keep seeing examples of people trying to cram far too much into a single regex

I would do it like this

- Remove bracketed substring followed by any number of non-word characters from the start of the string
- Remove any number of non-word characters followed by a price, and optional whitespace from the end of the string, capturing the price
- Assign the capture to `$price` if one was found

Handling the prefix and the suffix separately makes it much easier to write a clear solution, which looks like this. Unfortunately the mess of brackets and backslashes that describe the prefix can't be improved, unless you want to use `\[ [^][]* \]` which I don't think is significantly better

```
use strict;
use warnings 'all';
use feature 'say';

while ( <DATA> ) {
    chomp;
    s/ ^ \[ [^\[\]]* \] \W* //x;

    my $price;
    $price = $1 if s/ \W* (£[\d.]+)? \s* \z //x;

    say $_;
    say $price if $price;
}


__DATA__
[Foo] - Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt £34.99
[BARBAR] ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis £255.25
[BAZZ] - deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. - £500
```

#### output

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt
£34.99
ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis
£255.25
deserunt mollit anim id est laborum
£500
```

Comment: This looks like a very good solution, point taken about cramming too much into a single regex. Thanks

Comment: I've seen this trend too. I'm really not sure why - I mean, I suppose a 'power' regex seems pretty potent, but it... does exactly the thing that gives perl a bit of a bad rep. Adds complexity, reduces clarity, but without actually gaining much efficiency for all it's concise.

Comment: @Sobrique, please take a look at my edited question, there's an edge case I've just found.

Comment: If the discount is always bracketed like that, it should be trivial to adapt this answer.

Comment: @Sobrique my regex fu is weak, my brain today is weaker, I'm still trying to figure out how the above works, never mind adapt it :)

Comment: @Dr.Avalanche: Please don't treat Stack Overflow as if it were an internet forum: you're asking a new question. Also, it leaves a nasty taste in the mouth if people seem to be unwilling to write any code for themselves. Stack Overflow is a *knowledge base* like **Wikipedia**, so if you think of your question as being like a root page on Wiki then you have the right idea. Do you really imagine that there would be a lot of traffic for *this solution doesn't quite work*?

Comment: @Borodin "Please don't treat Stack Overflow as if it were an internet forum: you're asking a new question." Would you prefer I posted a new question? "Also, it leaves a nasty taste in the mouth if people seem to be unwilling to write any code for themselves." On this site I've written code for myself and to answer others. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl -w

use strict;

while (<>)
{
    chomp;
    if (/^\[[^\]]+\]\W+(.*?)(?:\W+(£\d+(?:\.\d{2})?))?$/)
    {
        print "line: $1\n";
        print "price: $2\n" if $2;
    }
}
```

Output:

```
line: Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt
price: £34.99
line: ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis
price: £255.25
line: deserunt mollit anim id est laborum
price: £500
```

Comment: You should `use warnings 'all'` in preference to `-w` on the command liune or shebang line

Comment: You should also use `chomp` instead of `chop`, and use style choices that aid *other people* rather than yourself, which mostly means using [perlstyle](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlstyle.html)

Comment: @Borodin, changed the `chop` to `chomp`, however I don't quite see what style changes you are alluding to. The only thing that I see is the position of the opening curly brackets, but that's really a matter of taste (I just hate trailing brackets), and I doubt that would be a problem for anyone. Anything else?